# Ext JS 6.2.0 Failed to upload an apk file to the web server

Tags: file-upload, extjs, apk, mime-types

I'm new on ExtJS. I need to upload an apk file to the server web. That work fine on Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Opera navigators but don't work on Firefox (It doesn't seem to correctly detect the file extension type).

Here is a part of the code I implemented:

```
{
  fieldLabel: 'File',
  xtype: 'filefield',
  name: 'FilePath',
  buttonText: 'Select',
  emptyText: 'Select an apk or zip file',
  accept: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive, application/zip',
  clearOnSubmit: false,
  allowBlank: container.opt === 'edit',
  maxFileSize: 50000000,  
  wrongFormatText: 'You must select a apk or zip file',
}
```

However when I upload a zip file, that work on all navigators.
Please I need help.

Comment: I don't think that any of the common web browsers will be able to provide an APK file with mime type `vnd.android.package-archive`. Most desktop systems don't know at all how to handle APK files.